# Gnome Panels and Task-Bar and Starter are gone / missing / disappeared

Tags: gnome, panel, taskbar, gnome-flashback

What happened?

Everything was working correctly, but then i did the following: 
Today, i **started Ubuntu** not with my current kernel like normally, but with an **older Kernel**, because i wanted to try something out.

After is started Ubuntu with the older kernel, i noted that **all my gnome settings are gone**/missing/disappeared.

For example:

- My Background-image gone
- Mouse-speed settings gone
- Nautilus settings gone
- Bottom-Task-Bar gone
- Panels (like Top/Bottom-Panels) gone

--> My Desktop looks pretty empty, only the icons for folders/files are visible.

At this point, i was not frightened about that, because I thought, that the reason for all these "missing settings" was, that i am on an "older" kernel right now.
So, i thought, my settings will be there again as normal, after changing back from the older to my current kernel.

BUT: 
After changing back to my current Kernel, all settings like Background-Image, Panels, ... are still missing :-(

I have a feeling, that the process, that runs gnome, does not have the correct **access-rights** anymore to read all my config-files (for Background, mouse-speed, Nautilus-settings, ....).

When logging in with **Guest-Account**, all Panels and Menu-Bars are there as normally adn are **working correct**. 
-> That means, all installed gnome packages are still working correctly, no need for any update or installation of things. 
It seems, its just a "settings-problem".

Can anyone help??

THANKS!!!!!

---

I am using:

- gnome-session-fallback (Metacity)
- indicator-applet-complete
- 4.4.0-143-generic (current kernel)
- Distributor ID:  Ubuntu
- Description: Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS
- Release: 14.04
- Codename:    trusty

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution: for some reason, `~/.config/dconf/user` was owned by `root`.
I just typed the following into a terminal:

```
sudo chown myself ~/.config/dconf/user
```

and then logged out and back. This solved the issue.